# ASP NET MVC 6 Web App hosted on Azure not running

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC 6 application which is hosted in Azure as web app. It is running fine on local by iisexpress but when I hosted it in Azure using publish option in Visual Studio, it is not working. It is just waiting to load website. After 4-5 minutes wait, it displays nothing.

I also tested it with static file. I uploaded a static html file in wwwroot folder but it is also not working.

I am not getting how can I see the actual error. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What happens if you try to start the app manually (App Services > Your App Service > Tools > Console > cd \home\site\approot and run the `web.cmd` in there)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've provided almost no information I gonna have to guess, since I had a similar error this weekend when deploying an ASP.NET Core 1.0 WebApp to an Azure App Service.

The issue I was facing was, that the main application wouldn't start. After a couple of hours trying to figure it out I got an error message with the method mentioned in the comments (running web.cmd manually) which returned an `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4089 EAFNOSUPPORT address family not supported` exception.

I couldn't find anything directly related to it, but was a hint about an IPv6 problem. A few other SO posts hinted that setting `http://*:12345` as port binds to both, IPv4 and IPv6. So after I changed the url to `http://0.0.0.0:12345` in the `hosting.json`, it started without issues.

I filled an [issue on Kestrel GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/766) and this seems to be a bug in Kestrel.

**Edit**: In response to the comment:

I used to have

```
{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "server.urls": "http://*:8081"
}
```

and changed it to

```
{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:8081"
}
```

The difference seems to be that `http://*:8081` also binds to both IPv4 and IPv6 on the same port, whereas `http://0.0.0.0:8081` only binds on IPv4 and not on IPv6.

Comment: What is the setting you added to `hosting.json`? Or what does your `hosting.json` file look like?

Comment: @Stephen: Updated my answer